# Finding conditions that $f(x)$ be integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f(x)$ be a continuously differentiable function. In addition, suppose that $f(x)$ is positive and $x\geq 0$. I am going to get conditions under which $f(x)$ turns out to be integrable. For instance, we say that if $f(x)$ satisfies the equation

$$
\dot{f}(x)+kf(x)\leq 0,
$$
where $k>0$, then $f(x)$ is integrable, i.e, $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=m<\infty$.
I am looking for other conditions such as the above equation to infer that $f(x)$ is integrable.

Comment: A silly one is that there exists a function $g$ such that $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \ge 0$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty g$ converges.

Comment: This will depend entirely on your definition of 'integrable' - do you mean that there exists a solution to $\dot{f}+kf=0$?

Comment: No, I mean I want to infer the integral of $f(x)$ in the interval $[0,\infty)$ exist.